# Multiline Inferences / Rules / Axioms in Bussproofs

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

I have a proof that I need to set in LaTeX, and to do so I am using the `bussproofs` package. However my proof has large amounts of free text in it, which makes the proof overly wide. Is there a way to use multi-line inferences? neither `\\` nor `\newline` seem to do the trick.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
    \AxiomC{Very long piece of text}
            \AxiomC{Even longer piece of text}
        \LeftLabel{Absurdly long rule name}
        \BinaryInfC{Another piece of excessively wordy text}
    \DisplayProof
\end{document}
```

[image: A very wide rule]

N.B. I am not using any `math` environments so using `align` or `gather` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used several commands from `stackengine`.  You should read the package docs to see what applies best for your case.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
    \AxiomC{\stackanchor{Very long}{piece of text}}
            \AxiomC{\stackanchor{Even longer}{piece of text}}
        \LeftLabel{\stackanchor{Absurdly long}{rule name}}
        \BinaryInfC{\Shortstack{{Another piece} of excessively {wordy text}}}
    \DisplayProof
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, in response to the comment, you just wanted formatted text, just use `\parbox`es:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}

\AxiomC{\parbox{.7in}{\raggedright Very long piece of text}}
\AxiomC{\parbox{.7in}{\raggedright Even longer piece of text}}
\LeftLabel{\parbox{.7in}{\raggedright Absurdly long rule name}}
\BinaryInfC{\parbox{.7in}{\raggedright Another piece of excessively wordy text}}
    \DisplayProof

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an environment that will cause the text to reflow naturally? Like I give a width and it reflows at some point less than that?

Comment: Just an FYI, the `\parbox` solution breaks if you have non-breaking equations, the proof line doesn't extend and the axiom intrudes on other axioms. The `stackengine` solution works perfectly.